# When is it useful to use a scoped pointer and when does it get destroyed?

Tags: c++, boost

I was reading some documentation about smart pointers and there are some questions left.
I am using the BOOST scoped_ptr which if my understanding is correct is a unique pointer. So I used a scoped pointer in the class *message_manager* to declare an object of *message_queue* from *boost::interprocess*.
I used this implementation because the *message_queue* object shall be initialized later and there is no default constructor to be used instead.

1. Is this a valid usecase for a scoped pointer?
2. In my understanding the scoped pointer gets automatically destroyed when the scope ends but when does the scope end? Does it end when the object of *message_manager* is destroyed?

Many thanks already.

message manager.h

```
#include "boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp"
#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include "data_storage.h"

using namespace boost::interprocess;

class message_manager
{
private:
    boost::scoped_ptr<message_queue> mq;
public:
    message_manager();
    void send_msg(char message, unsigned int priority);
    char receive_msg(unsigned int priority);
    int createQUEUE(string name);
    int destroyQUEUE(string name);
};
```

message_manager.cpp

```
int message_manager::createQUEUE(string name)
{
    mq.reset(new message_queue(open_or_create, name.c_str(), 100, sizeof(int)));

    cout << "Created queue named:" << name << endl;

    return 1;
};

int message_manager::destroyQUEUE(string name)
{
    if (mq->remove(name.c_str()))
    {
        cout << "Destroyed queue named:" << name << endl;
        return 1;
    } 
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not destroy queue named:" << name << endl;
        return 0;
    }

};
```

Comment: That's not exactly where I'd expect a scoped_ptr, not that there's anything wrong with it, but that's not a scope, and you're not gaining much. However, scoped_ptr can't be moved or copied, so message_manager can't be moved or copied. I'd probably go with std::unique_ptr there.

Comment: Do you understand scope?

Answer (score 2):

> When is it useful to use a scoped pointer

Before C++11.

As far as I know, all use cases have been obsoleted by `unique_ptr` which can be found in the standard library.

> when does it get destroyed?

The type of an object doesn't have an effect on when the object is destroyed. In this case the scoped pointer is a member variable, and member variables are destroyed when the class that contains them is destroyed.

Scoped pointer has unique ownership of the pointed object, and the pointed object is destroyed when the scoped pointer is destroyed.

> I used this implementation because the message_queue object shall be initialized later and there is no default constructor to be used instead.
> Is this a valid usecase for a scoped pointer?

`std::optional` (or the boost equivalent, if you need pre C++17 support) might be more appropriate in this case rather than any smart pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So whats the alternative for a scoped pointer if it should not be used anymore?

Comment: @mxmlntr `unique_ptr`. The standard has it, and boost has it as well. I don't know why someone would use the boost version, but it's there.